# Affecting several images when I do hovering in HTML

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to hover on image. When I do hover on it the opacity of the image will be  decreased and the text will appear on the image. I kinda did something.  In my container I have 3 different images which are  under same class name. I think that's why when I hover one image other two image is affected .How can I fix it?  Sİnce I hve been trying to solve it for a long time, My brain stopped working.

What I want when I hover one image, only that image will be affected. Here is my code. Thanks all

```
         <div class="main-blog-items">
                    <div class="blog-baslik">
                        <h4>BLOG & HABERLER</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="blog-icerik">
                                <div class="blog-img">
                                    <img src="img/carousel2.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="overlay-blog">
                                    <div class="blog-content">Blog Yazısı 1</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog-item-title">
                                <p>Title</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    .overlay-blog {
                transition: .5s ease;
                opacity: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            
            
            .main-blog-items:hover .blog-img {
                opacity: 0.3;
            
            }
            .main-blog-items:hover .blog-item-title{
                opacity: -5;
            
            
            }
            .main-blog-items:hover .overlay-blog {
                opacity: 1;
            
            }
```

Comment: Then put the hover on the image not the parent container

Comment: I am new on the HTML, what do you mean?

Comment: if you mean like this:  .blog-image img:hover { opacity: 0.3;} , I tried still it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this instead

```
.blog-icerik:hover  {
opacity: 0.3;

}
.blog-icerik:hover  .overlay-blog {
opacity: 1;

}

.blog-icerik:hover ~ .blog-item-title{
opacity: 0;


}
```